# Reading last line - 1

Tags: vb.net

I've created a simple program to read our login logs from the different users that work here. The program is working fine however, I want to be able to scroll trough the entries.

Every line in the log has a entry like this and the line count is uncertain as it depends on if and how many times the user logs in:

```
ussername;siteserver;loginserver;hostname;ipaddress;;windowsversion;datetime
```

I'm able to get the last line and display it in a dialog with this sub:

```
Dim title As String = "LogViewer"
        Dim SearchName As String = SearchInput.Text
        SearchName = SearchName.ToUpper()

        If Not SearchLog(SearchName) Is Nothing Then
            If (InStr(SearchName, "PC") Or InStr(SearchName, "NB")) Then

                System.Diagnostics.Debug.WriteLine(SearchLog(SearchName))
                Dim lines As String() = File.ReadAllLines(SearchLog(SearchName))
                Dim firstLine As String = lines.First
                Dim lastLine As String = lines.Last

                Dim SplitString() As String = lastLine.Split(";")
                Dim msg As New DeviceLog(SplitString(0), SplitString(1), SplitString(2), SplitString(3), SplitString(4), SplitString(5))
                msg.ShowDialog()
            Else
                SearchName = SearchName.ToLower
                System.Diagnostics.Debug.WriteLine(SearchLog(SearchName))
                Dim lines As String() = File.ReadAllLines(SearchLog(SearchName))
                Dim firstLine As String = lines.First
                Dim lastLine As String = lines.Last

                Dim SplitString() As String = lastLine.Split(";")
                Dim Usermsg As New UserLog(SplitString(3), SplitString(0), SplitString(4), SplitString(6), SplitString(7))
                Usermsg.ShowDialog()
            End If

        Else
            Dim msg As String = "Cannot Find Host or Username."
            MsgBox(msg, , title)

        End If
    End Sub
```

Is there a way I get the last line - 1 and let it increment somehow with a counter attached to a button. How would I go about this. Any suggestions ?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

> Is there a way I get the last line - 1 and let it increment somehow with a counter

You could use `Enumerable.Reverse` and `Enumerable.Skip`:

```
Dim reverse = lines.Reverse()
For counter As Int32 = 0 To lines.Length - 1
    Dim line = reverse.Skip(counter).First()
Next
```

Instead of that loop you could use an `Int32`-property `Counter`

Comment: Thank you for the information and I'm almost there.
I now have this function: 
Public Function ChangeLine(ByVal SearchName As String)
        ' Read Log File To String
        Dim lines As String() = File.ReadAllLines(SearchLog(SearchName))

        Dim reverse = lines.Reverse()
        For counter As Int32 = 0 To lines.Length - 1
            Dim LogLine = reverse.Skip(counter).First()
            Return LogLine
        Next

    End Function
It's only returning the last line. Can this be controlled by a button, so that it incremenets at a click ?

Comment: You can make it more efficient and even more concise, you don't need the loop at all: `Array.Reverse(lines, 0, lines.Length) Return lines.Skip(Counter).First()`. This presumes that `Counter` is an `Int32`-property in your class which you can increment on button-click.